# Android MultiSelectListPreference, java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Tags: android, android-preferences

I try to implement MultiSelectListPreference for my settings view:

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
    android:title="@string/title"
    android:summary="@string/message"
    android:key="pref_foobar"
    android:defaultValue="@array/empty_array"
    android:entries="@array/fooArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/fooValues" />
```

The array:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="fooArray">
        <item>Foo</item>
        <item>Bar</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="fooValues">
        <item>foo_value</item>
        <item>bar_value</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="empty_array"/>
</resources>
```

However this gives me following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.myproject/.SettingsActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.util.Set

Full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/kBDByXY5

Any ideas whats wrong?

---

Code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT = "SETTINGS_FRAGMENT";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferenceFragment(), TAG_SETTINGS_FRAGMENT).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PreferenceFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment{

        public PreferenceFragment() {
            //required
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you  paste the code here please ?

Comment: @AIL there is no special code, because the settings are created from xml. `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` does all the magic.

Comment: If I copy paste your code in my android project, I have no problem. Rebuild the project and tell us if the problem persists

Comment: This issue keeps coming up, so my 2 cents... if you can't find your way out of it (no matter how many times i uninstalled the app from my device, i kept getting the same error), change the preference name and re-run the project, that should work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It feels like you already have a plain `String` preference under this key on your device or emulator. Try completely uninstalling and reinstalling the app, or using "Clear Data" for the app in its screen in Settings, to wipe out your existing `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Yup, this was it. I was messing around with all the different preferences types and when I finally settled on ListPreference it started to get an error "java.util.hash cannot be cast as java.lang.String". Uninstalling the app from my device and simply running it from Android Studio again fixed the issue.

Comment: I swear by CommonsWare, sheer Android Genius you are Thank you!

Comment: I just uninstalled my app and reinstall it, and app stopped crashing. thanks

Comment: Deleting app data works for me too after hours of trying to fix the issues which in real doesn't exists